# Replace all files and folders in branch with (currently) non-git folder

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

*Bear in mind that I am totally new to Git and don't know much of the terminology*

I have a branch, `reference-redo` on a GitHub repository and a different (non-git) folder which I would like to replace the contents of the `reference-redo` branch with.

Opening up the folder in Git bash:

`git init`: adds a `.git` folder (says it initialised an empty Git repository)

`git add .`: adds all files and folders (has a warning about LF being replaced by CR LF but no errors)

`git commit -m 'Fixed usage of references for ObjectPointer type'`: 'create mode ...' for the 14 files

`git remote add origin https://github.com/me/repo-name.git`: no output but also no errors

`git checkout -b reference-redo`: Switched to new branch 'reference-redo'

`git remote -v`

`git push origin reference-redo`

```
 ! [rejected]        reference-redo -> reference-redo (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/repo-name.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This seems to happen because I am *replacing* the branch's files, not *updating* it. Will I have to push to a new branch or can I push this current directory?

running `git remote show origin` shows that the branch does exist:

```
  Remote branches:
    functions      new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    master         new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    reference-redo new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master         pushes to master         (local out of date)
    reference-redo pushes to reference-redo (local out of date)
```

[git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the whole history in that branch, you can `git push --force`.

Otherwise, do a regular update by deleting and copying files in your local file manager and commit like any other time.

Comment: Is this the same as `-f` and are there any potential negative consequences?

Comment: It is. Yes, it is problematic if other people have already fetched that branch.